# How to show Subtotal of Groups in Telerik Radgrid using a post back or pressing a button?

Tags: telerik, radgrid, subtotal

In **telerik radgrid**, as **subtotal calculation** of **groups** is not possible in client side (I have searched a lot already), I thought about placing a button which will post back the page and on the server side, it will rebind the radgrid and will also show the subtotals of the groups. I don't have any code now, it will be fine if someone helps me with some example.

Comment: "I don't have any code now" So there is no question? Make a simple grid with simple data 2 or 3 row if you want, add a group header with the calcul you need. Then come back with a [mcve].

Comment: For now you have no car but want us to provide a clear exemple on how to close the back seat window.